# Trying to use Cartopy but this error occurs: URLError: <urlopen error [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution>

Tags: python, spatial, netcdf, cartopy

I was using basemap for spatial mapping for .nc files for a long time, but I saw that now it is recommended to use cartopy instead. I made the transition and, initially, all went well, but after a while it doesnt work anymore, and this error keeps spaming over and over again, I've tried to reshape the code, change the projection, but its always this URLError: **<urlopen error [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution>**.

Here is the code for you guys have a look

```
import cartopy.feature as cfeature
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
from cartopy.mpl.gridliner import LATITUDE_FORMATTER, LONGITUDE_FORMATTER
import xarray as xr
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.colors as colors
import numpy as np

ds = xr.open_mfdataset('/content/pr_SAM-22_ECMWF-ERAINT_evaluation_r1i1p1_ICTP-RegCM4-svn_v0_day_*_remap.nc')

prec = ds['pr']*86400

prec_sel = prec.sel(lon=slice(-80, -30), lat=slice(-60, 8),time='2017-12-01T12:00:00')

colors = ["#b4f0f0", "#96d2fa", "#78b9fa", "#3c95f5", "#1e6deb", "#1463d2", "#0fa00f", "#28be28", "#50f050", "#72f06e", "#b3faaa", "#fff9aa", "#ffe978", "#ffc13c", "#ffa200", "#ff6200", "#ff3300", "#ff1500", "#c00100", "#a50200", "#870000", "#653b32"]
cmap = matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap(colors)
cmap.set_over('#000000')
cmap.set_under('#aaaaaa')

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))

ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())

ax.set_extent([-80, -30, 8, -60])

lon, lat = np.meshgrid(prec_as.lon, prec_as.lat)

min = np.min(prec_as)
max = np.max(prec_as)
interval = 10
#levels = np.arange(min,max,interval)

S1 = plt.contourf(lon, lat, prec_as, linewidths = 1.5, extend='both')

plt.colorbar(S1,ticks=np.arange(min,200,interval),format='%.1f')

ax.add_feature(cfeature.COASTLINE)

ax.add_feature(cfeature.BORDERS)

states = cfeature.NaturalEarthFeature(category='cultural',
                                      name='admin_1_states_provinces_shp',
                                      scale='50m',
                                      facecolor='none')
ax.add_feature(states, edgecolor='k', linestyle='--')

ax.set_title('Test', fontsize=14, y=1.02)

g1 = ax.gridlines(crs=ccrs.PlateCarree(), linestyle='--', color='gray', draw_labels=True)

g1.ylabels_right = False
g1.xlabels_top = False

g1.yformatter = LATITUDE_FORMATTER
g1.xformatter = LONGITUDE_FORMATTER

g1.xlabel_style = {'size': 14}
g1.ylabel_style = {'size': 14}

plt.savefig('Mapa_streamlines_AS.png', dpi=300, bbox_inches='tight')
```

And this is the error:

> /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/cartopy/mpl/geoaxes.py:1586:
> UserWarning: linewidths is ignored by contourf   result =
> matplotlib.axes.Axes.contourf(self, *args, **kwargs)
> /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/cartopy/mpl/gridliner.py:360:
> UserWarning: The .ylabels_right attribute is deprecated. Please use
> .right_labels to toggle visibility instead.   warnings.warn('The
> .ylabels_right attribute is deprecated. Please '
> /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/cartopy/mpl/gridliner.py:324:
> UserWarning: The .xlabels_top attribute is deprecated. Please use
> .top_labels to toggle visibility instead.   warnings.warn('The
> .xlabels_top attribute is deprecated. Please '
> /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/cartopy/io/**init**.py:241:
> DownloadWarning: Downloading:
> https://naciscdn.org/naturalearth/110m/physical/ne_110m_coastline.zip
> warnings.warn('Downloading: {}'.format(url), DownloadWarning)
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- gaierror                                  Traceback (most recent call
> last) /usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py in do_open(self,
> http_class, req, **http_conn_args)    1349
> h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,
> -> 1350                           encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))    1351
> except OSError as err: # timeout error
>
> 35 frames gaierror: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> URLError                                  Traceback (most recent call
> last) /usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py in do_open(self,
> http_class, req, **http_conn_args)    1350
> encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))    1351
> except OSError as err: # timeout error
> -> 1352                 raise URLError(err)    1353             r = h.getresponse()    1354         except:
>
> URLError: <urlopen error [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name
> resolution> Error in callback <function
> install_repl_displayhook..post_execute at 0x7f10349a6cb0> (for
> post_execute):
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- gaierror                                  Traceback (most recent call
> last) /usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py in do_open(self,
> http_class, req, **http_conn_args)    1349
> h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,
> -> 1350                           encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))    1351
> except OSError as err: # timeout error
>
> 35 frames gaierror: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> URLError                                  Traceback (most recent call
> last) /usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py in do_open(self,
> http_class, req, **http_conn_args)    1350
> encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))    1351
> except OSError as err: # timeout error
> -> 1352                 raise URLError(err)    1353             r = h.getresponse()    1354         except:
>
> URLError: <urlopen error [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name
> resolution>
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- gaierror                                  Traceback (most recent call
> last) /usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py in do_open(self,
> http_class, req, **http_conn_args)    1349
> h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,
> -> 1350                           encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))    1351
> except OSError as err: # timeout error
>
> 35 frames gaierror: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> URLError                                  Traceback (most recent call
> last) /usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py in do_open(self,
> http_class, req, **http_conn_args)    1350
> encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))    1351
> except OSError as err: # timeout error
> -> 1352                 raise URLError(err)    1353             r = h.getresponse()    1354         except:
>
> URLError: <urlopen error [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name
> resolution>

As I said, I've tried to change each block that corresponds to cartopy, even changing the .shp to one with only the countries, but nothing works.

Comment: Are you able to open that URL in a browser?

Comment: you mean this: https://naciscdn.org/naturalearth/110m/physical/ne_110m_coastline.zip ? If so, no, I cant, and also tried to change the .zip file. I have the .shp that I downloaded from another source, is there a way to put in instead of use ulrlib?

Comment: The old Natural Earth server is broken.  The next Cartopy version will download from AWS.  For discussion of ways to access the downloads in the meantime, see https://github.com/SciTools/cartopy/issues/1849

Comment: Cartopy v0.20 has now been released, so this issue should be resolved by upgrading to that.